# Fixtures breaking rails minitest Error: NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest, fixtures

All my tests on rails are giving me errors. The following is an example of the error.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
test/fixtures/exhibition_works.yml:26:in `get_binding'
```

The line of code in my fixture that it points is the following.

```
child_exhibition_work:
  exhibition_id: <%= Exhibition.third.id %>
  work_id: <%= Work.first.id %>
```

It is a little confusing and I have not be able to find a solution to this. Especially when there is another developer that is running the test with the same fixtures and they are working.

Please if any one has any insight that would be great

**Work fixture**
work.yml

```
one:
  title: MyString
  date: 2013-10-09
  media_type: 1
  height: MyString
  width: MyString
  dimention_notes: MyText
  bin: MyString
  signed: MyString
  tags: MyString
  condition: MyString
  status: MyString
  is_edition: false
  inscription: MyString
  raisonne_number: MyString
```

**Exhibition fixture**
exhibitions.yml

```
one:
  exhibition_title: MyString
  description: MyText
  group_show: false

two:
  exhibition_title: MyString
  description: MyText
  group_show: false

three:
  exhibition_title: MyString
  description: MyText
```

Comment: do you have an exhibitions fixture?  Is the test referencing it? The same questions for the works fixture. BTW, usually you reference another fixture by using its tags. ```exhibition: name_of_an_exhibition``` entry

Comment: Yes I do have an exhibition fixture and a work fixture as well. It does seem like the the reason why it is breaking may correlated to the reference to id being within an erb line. I guess I am a little confused why it may work for someone else.

As per your suggestions of referencing through a tag. How would I put this in the fixture. Would it be like this 

```
child_exhibition_work:
  exhibition: third
  work: first
```

Comment: would be helpful if you added a few entries for your works and exhibitions fixtures to your question.  Asking your colleague what they did probably your best solution.

Comment: @dbugger I added examples of the other fixtures. You are right asking my colleague would probably be best. We are working on different time zones so I was searching for solutions right now.

Comment: ```child_exhibition_work:
  exhibition: three
  work: one```

Comment: I've just run into this exact error when including any ERB in my fixtures. Did you end up finding a solution?